# How Carbon-Nylon propellers compare to other materials

Tags: propellers, material

Carbon fiber propellers consensus seems: more precision but lower flight time compared to common plastic propellers.
But... what about **Carbon-Nylon** composite propellers that are basically made in Nylon infused with carbon fibers to increase stiffness?

I'm looking for best efficiency to increase flight time, the Carbon-Nylon propellers are sold as some kind of premium propeller and are around more than twice the price of ABS propellers, I have no doubts they will be durable, but despite they are available since years on the market I haven't found any data or test to compare their performances to other materials as ABS, fiberglass, Nylon in terms of **efficiency**.